# Button Print Toast When Clicked without answer Given

Tags: android

I have this button which calls two methods. See Code; Now i have tried to add a method on my onPictureSubmit(v) method which will print a Toast message (Please Submit Answer) if someone clicked the button without submitting an answer. Problem is it keeps crushing. Any help on how i can detect someone clicked the button without submitting answer will be appreciated.

My Button Code;

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (pass) {
            case 0:
                onDefinitionSubmit(v);
                break;
            case 1:
                onPictureSubmit(v);

                break;
            case 2
                break;

        }


    }
```

My Code :

```
private void onPictureSubmit(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.picture_submit) {
            final int answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.picture_answer)).getText());
            final int answerKey = com.madonasystematixnote.mathhelper.lessons.PictureFragment.answer;
            final int x = Integer.parseInt("" + ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_x)).getText());
            final int y = Integer.parseInt("" + ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_y)).getText());


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd declare the `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button` as a global variable, and then in your `onCreate()` I'd use the `findViewById()` to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Second, I'd check if the `answerGiven` (I guess is the answer) it's empty, so I'd create a method that returns me if it's empty or not the `EditText`.

```
public boolean isEtEmpty(String str){
  if(str.isEmpty() || str.length() == 0 || str.equals("") || str == null){
      return true;
  }
  else{
      return false;
  }
}
```

Then at the time you call `onPictureSubmit()` call this method doing this :

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.picture_submit) {
if (isEtEmpty(picture_answer.getText())){ //picture_answer is the EditText that you want to know if it's empty or not
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please Submit Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
final int answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.picture_answer)).getText());
final int answerKey = com.madonasystematixnote.mathhelper.lessons.PictureFragment.answer;
final int x = Integer.parseInt("" + ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_x)).getText());
final int y = Integer.parseInt("" + ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_y)).getText());
}
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, i actually decided to catch all exception :) And i Upvoted your answer :)

Comment: If you think my answer helped you feel free to makr it as a correct :P